# Get ADF pipelines status using az cli - bash script

Tags: bash, azure, shell, automation, azure-data-factory

I have been trying to get adf pipelines status using az cli script.
I am using

`az datafactory pipeline-run query-by-factory --factory-name "adfname" --filters operand="Status" operator="Equals" values="Failed" --last-updated-after "2023-01-17T00:00:00.3345758Z" --last-updated-before "2023-01-17T11:59:59.3686473Z" --resource-group "rgname"`

command and I am getting full json of pipelines but I only want name and status of these pipelines. I have tried using jQuery like --query "pipelineName", --query "status". Pipeline is succeeding but I am not getting any results.
Please help me for the issue if anyone have knowledge about it.

I am expecting result like pipelineName -- status.
e.g.,

pl_databricks -- Failed
pl_databricks_mq -- Succeeded.

If possible date and time also

pl_databricks    -- Failed    -- 23/12/22 10:29:27
pl_databricks_mq -- Succeeded -- 23/12/22 08:20:50

Answer (score 0):

- I have  reproduced in my environment and got outputs as below:

```
$Target=@()

$x=az datafactory pipeline-run query-by-factory --factory-name "adfname" --filters operand="Status" operator="Equals" values="Succeeded" --last-updated-after "2023-01-15T00:00:00.3345758Z" --last-updated-before "2023-06-16T00:36:44.3345758Z" --resource-group "rgname"

$r=$x | ConvertFrom-Json

$Target= $r.value.pipelinename +" "+ $r.value.status

$Target
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @tarun-krishna. I have already got the solution by trial and error